# ViewPager with two fragments containing set of cards

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having an activity with a viewPager which holds two fragments. For example, let's name the two fragments as Fragment A and Fragment B. Each of the fragments are having a set of cards. If suppose, I select a set of cards from fragment A and swipe to fragment B, the selected cards still remain selected when I swipe back to fragment A. How do I deselect them on swiping to the  fragment B?

Answer (score 0):

Use replace() method while doing fragment transaction. It will remove all the previous fragment from the containerView and add the new one.